# An application that notifies of new emails

Tags: windows-7, gmail

I need an application which alerts me when I have new Gmail messages. I have [Gmail notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html) installed on my laptop but it lacks two important features I need it to have:

- It doesn't make a sound when alerting
- The notifications goes away after a few minutes and I miss them when I'm away from computer

Do you know of one?

As it might be important, when I run Gmail notifier I always get this error:

> Cannot connect to your mailbox, Service temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Since GMail allows IMAP connections, I suggest you enable IMAP on your account and search for IMAP mail notifiers. You'll find a billion of them; find one you like.

Comment: *Or* find a Google Talk (XMPP) client that is capable of displaying mail notifications. (For example, Gajim.)

Comment: @RichHomolka: Thank you so much, that worked. I installed [this one](http://gmailassistant.sourceforge.net/). The only problem I'm facing is, when I run the app, "num lk" and "caps lock" keeps flashing. DO you have any ideas? And if you like to post it as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since GMail allows IMAP connections, I suggest you enable IMAP on your account and search for IMAP mail notifiers. You'll find a billion of them; find one you like.

As far as the specific one you mentioned, it seems to need java, which is a bit heavyweight for what you're asking. Not that there's anything wrong with java apps, but it means you need to keep up with java updates - there are occasional holes in java.

A google search came up with this: [IMAPnotify](http://www.vandyke.com/download/imapnotify/). This is from VanDyke, a reputable firm that's been around for a bit. It may be old code, so not sure how it would work on Win7.

Answer (score 0):

I use Trillian which is an all in one chat client but also allows you to add your gmail account, any new emails that come in get a pop-up and an alert sound is made. I use this to consolidate all my different email accounts in one easy interface.

Trillian: http://www.trillian.im/